# How can I host a static website with GitLab authentication in front of it?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab repo that generates a static website, pushed to either GitLab Pages or Amazon S3. I want to limit access to this static website to members of a certain GitLab group/sub-group. What is the lowest maintenance way to accomplish this?

Using AWS is permissible for this task, but I want to stop short of deploying this site on its own EKS container or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab Pages has built-in access controls.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/pages_access_control.html